# Read Phone State Reciever not working on real device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have tested my reciever on emulator and simulate face call to emulator and can log phone state even get calling number,
However if i try this on real device, it is not working. I added an activity and if it working background, it works. But why should i add it? Why has to activity run  on background?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context cnx, Intent nt) {
    Bundle bnd = nt.getExtras();
    Log.e("EXTRA", "EXTRA");
    if (bnd != null) {
        String state = bnd.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.i("PHONE STATE", state);



        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.i("PHONE STATE",
                    bnd.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity meant to be run in Foreground, If you want to run your process in Background you should use Services.
[read here more](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

For your question, You should have *separate class for receiver*, Register receiver in Manifest file for Phone state change action and with permission to read phone state.

Comment: Dear Ankit,
I have already register my reciever in manifest and gave neccessary permission. It works emulator without using any activity or service. However it doesnot work on real device. What is the reason?